# How do i make this simple test in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have the following test:

```
describe("An Angularjs test suite",function(){
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  var scope,controller;
  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller){
    scope = $rootScope.$new(),
    controller = $controller('homeController',{$scope:scope});
  }));

  it('should return true',function(){
    expect(scope.helloWorld()).toBe('hello');
  });
});
```

in the homecontroller i have this:

```
$scope.helloWorld = function(){
                return 'hello';
            };
```

test runs faulty and said 'undefined is not a function', what is the problem?

Comment: Post the complete error message and stack trace, and the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    (function (angular) {
        // Create module
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
        myApp.controller('homeController', function($scope){
        $scope.helloWorld = function(){
            return 'hello';  
        };
    });
})(angular);



// ---SPECS-------------------------

describe('myApp', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));
    var scope,controller;
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope,$controller){
        scope = $rootScope.$new(),
        controller = $controller('homeController',{$scope:scope});
    }));
    it('should return true',function(){
        expect(scope.helloWorld()).toBe('hello');
    });
});
```

Just create a [TestCase](http://jsfiddle.net/tyler_z_yang/qgog5y1a/1/)  here.

And it passed.

Comment: I don't understand, what's the diffrence between this answer to the one i wrote, why is it working here?

Comment: I suggest you to post all your code to jsfiddle(You'd better fork my jsfiddle to do that, and if it works. Suggest you to change your jasmine lib.).